# Swift add value to existing child

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm really struggling to understand how to work the firebase realtime database.

For my practice event app, once the event is created I store the values here under the child "firstDisplay":

[image]

The user info exists separately under the child "users":

[image]

When the event is created I use the code

```
var userListing: DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference().child("users").child("listings")
userListing.updateChildValues([newGroupRefAsString: 1])
```

To take the reference of the event under "firstDisplay" and add it to the users information under a new child called "listings" so I can keep track of which user has made which event. However as you can see in the picture it creates a new child every time, I have tried a million things and cant seem to move the child listings into the child users.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Now there's `.child("users").child("listings")` your problem. That path is */users/listings* and you want */users/users uid/listings*, right? Try `.child("users").child(users uid).child("listings")`.  I assume the node key 3PwXvq... is the users uid...

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I tried that code and it showed an error. But it got me thinking I am trying to go through the uid, so I put in similar code to use the uid.

 var userListing: DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).child("listings")

which works perfectly. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Hmm. That's exactly what I suggested in my comment... lol. Glad it worked!

Comment: Oh I think I see now. It was like 4am when I was trying to figure this out after a long day. Thanks for helping me.